# Can I import photos from iPad to iMac that aren't in camera roll?

Tags: macos, ipad, mac, photos.app

I lost all data on my iMac recently, including some 1500 photos.  These photos were synced to the iPad from iPhoto on my iMac.

How can I transfer them back to my iMac since they are not in the camera roll on my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

[iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) is an app that does the trick. I just tested it, and it works.

So it's quite simple and straightforward. Launch the app, and select you iPad from the sources, there will be a Photos section, and everything should be there.

The same thing happened to me once, but I used Time Machine to backup. It must be terrifying, anyway, hope it helps!

Comment: seems to work well